# Visual Studio/Xamarin No rsc found that matches the given name

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

So basically I was trying to to add a cover image on my application but unfortunately when trying to build the application it came up with one of the errors I couldn't solve out I was trying to add a cover image with different name however it didn't work out at all. Nota Bene I'm kind of a noob  to this sort of problem so sorry, just in case, first time using stackoverflow. I was trying to look up for the answer before.
Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
              <color android:color="@color/splashBackground"/>
</item>
  <item>
    <bitmap
      android:src="@drawable/Cover"
     android:scaleType="matrix"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:tileMode="disabled"
/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Error list output:

*Severity   Code    Description Project Path    File    Line    Source  Suppression State
Error       No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/Cover').  Uber Raider C:\Users***\Documents\xamarin\uber\Uber Raider\Uber Raider\Resources\drawable  C:\Users***\Documents\xamarin\uber\Uber Raider\Uber Raider\Resources\drawable\splash.xml   2   Build*

Comment: does your drawable folder contain an image named "Cover"?

Comment: Yep, it does.
 However, i found the solution, i've just deleted the file and added it again, through the solution Explorer, (even thought i've tried this before, and it seems to work now)

Comment: @Kamil,It seems that you have solved your issue now, please remember to give one reply and mark your reply as answer,thanks. It is beneficial to other community members who face the same issue.